# Rotating geometry in cartopy?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, cartopy

I would like to use `cartopy` to display a map of the cities in the contiguous United States. In order to do so, I have written the following code (the data comes from [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/usgs-small-scale-dataset-cities-and-towns-of-the-united-states-201403-shapefile)):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cities = gpd.read_file("./data/citiesx010g.shp")
cities_m = cities[cities['STATE'].map(lambda s: s not in ['PR', 'AK', 'HI', 'VI'])]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=ccrs.AlbersEqualArea())
ax.scatter([p.x for p in cities_m.geometry], [p.y for p in cities_m.geometry], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image]

This leads to the following three questions:

1. In this case, what would I have to do to "flip" this plot right side up?
2. In the general case of having some kind of data in a `AlbersEqualArea` projection, what would I have to do to "flip" that data right side up?
3. In the most general case of having just about any projection, how would I go about "flipping" the data right side up? (only the naive `PlateCarree` always comes out "right").

Answer (score 2):

This effect occurs because by default points you draw are rendered as though they are on a globe or map, rendered in the current projection, centered on the point `(0, 0)`. This map then gets "cut" to fit the points in your display.

This means that only points near `(0, 0)` will look "right".

You can adjust this center by specifying `central_latitude` and `central_longitude` parameters. Here's the corrected code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cities = gpd.read_file("./data/citiesx010g.shp")
cities_m = cities[cities['STATE'].map(lambda s: s not in ['PR', 'AK', 'HI', 'VI'])]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_latitude=39.5, central_longitude=-98.35))
ax.scatter([p.x for p in cities_m.geometry], [p.y for p in cities_m.geometry], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.show()
```